# scope of done event in $.ajax

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery $.ajax to add elements on-the-fly to my database.

The server-side returns the ID of the element recently added, and I want to capture that in my  done event block.

```
        if(!key) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/tags/add",
                type: "GET",
                data: {tagName:value}
            }).done(function(data){
                key = data;
            });
        }
```

/tags/add returns:

`return new Response($tags[0]->getId(), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/html'));`

where Response is framework specific.

If I go to the URL /tags/add?tagName=123

it will attempt to add that tag to the database if it doesn't exist. If it is succesful, it will return its id.

In the example above, in returns `63`

but the done function doesn't seem to be catching that `63` (or whatever the number is)

Here's the catch.

Let's assume the tag `dogs` doesn't exist:

1) `/tags/add?tagName=dogs` will add `dogs` to the database, and will return ID `64`

2) If I do `console.log(data)` in the first line inside the done event block, it will log `0` (default ID when the tag doesn't exist)

3) If I try to add `dogs` tag again to the database, `/tags/add?tagName=dogs` will see that `dogs` already exists, and will only return its id (`64`)

4) Then `console.log(data)` kicks in again, and it logs `64`

Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: The value of `data` will be the response from your server; if that's not what you're expecting then it sounds like the issue is with the server-side code.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but if I navigate to the URL directly the server-side response is correct.

Comment: If your tagname doesn't exists, it is supposed to return new inserted ID or 0? I don't understand where is your problem here

Comment: @roasted It's supposed to return the ID of the newly inserted row, and does so when navigating to the URL directly. Calling the URL via an AJAX request returns `0` incorrectly the first time (when the new row is inserted), but returns the correct ID on subsequent calls. That's how I'm interpreting the question, but took me a few reads to get there.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that's right, sorry for wording incorrectly the question.

Comment: @AlanChavez Not sure what to tell you; the jQuery looks fine, and the value of `data` will be the server response. Can you step through the server side code and see what's happening differently when doing it via AJAX?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist so ya, seems to be a server side issue

Comment: I already found the error, it wasn't server side... the problem was the asynchronous nature of ajax, for my snippet to work ajax had to work synchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the asynchronous nature of ajax.

all I needed to do to capture the server response correctly outside the `done` block was to set `async` to false.

```
    if(!key) {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "/tags/add",
            type: "GET",
            data: {tagName:value}
        }).done(function(data){
            key = data;
        });
    }
```

Comment: `async: false` is _never_ the right answer.  It's not even supposed to work with `.done` deferred methods.

Comment: I understand the consequences of async: false, basically if the server never responds my script will wait until the server does.

Comment: yes, pretty much.  There are always ways around this that don't involve using `return`.

Comment: it would be really helpful if you point me to the right direction :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call     I always use the "deferred" object syntax myself.